# Sqoop export is failing. Can't parse input data:'<data>'

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

When I run the sqoop export command from the terminal, it works fine. But if I run the same command from the oozie workflow it is throwing me the following error.

```
ror: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:122)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '2018-05-14,967,893,74,8863.330000000005,7617.07,1246.26'
at adjust_jazz_compare.__loadFromFields(adjust_jazz_compare.java:512)
at adjust_jazz_compare.parse(adjust_jazz_compare.java:430)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
... 10 more Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
at adjust_jazz_compare.__loadFromFields(adjust_jazz_compare.java:482)
... 12 more
```

Below is the command i am using

```
export --connect <jdbc> --username <user> --password <pass> --table <table> --export-dir <dir> --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

Table properties in hive

```
hive.inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{field.delim=,, serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{totalSize=3973, numRows=70, rawDataSize=3903, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE=true, numFiles=1, transient_lastDdlTime=1530647041}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The row which contains
    `"'2018-05-14,967,893,74,8863.330000000005,7617.07,1246.26'"` is not able to parsed in sqoop.

From Hive terminal check the proper format of this row.May be some special character or some spaces are there because of that this data is not able to parsed.

Please share the Schema of table present in hive.And also your hive query.

Comment: I have updated my question with table properties. I am just trying to export my hive complete table to mysql. No specific query

Comment: my doubt is, if i can do it through the terminal, why is it failing with a oozie job?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how did you create the table? Maybe you forget about fields delimiter in Hive?

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Example create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
    eid int, 
    name String,
    salary String, 
    destination String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```